# COD:MW3 Exploding Cash In Online

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

So, I've been playing Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3 on my PS3 for a while now and it's really starting to get on my nerves that every time someone gets killed on multiplayer they explode money everywhere. I've searched and searched, but cannot seem to find where to turn this off and display either A) Blood or B) Nothing. Both would be preferable to dropping money when I get killed. Does anyone know how, or even if, I can change/disable this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you can disable on PC but there is no way to disable this on PS3 or Xbox 360 as it is actually a reward system, just so you know the pc fix requires third party software to disable.

This does not happen everytime though, it is only due to what is called a payback kill, when someone kills you after you killed them first this is what triggers it in case you wondered.

Comment: I'd advise that you do -not- use third party applications of any sort with the PC version as you run a real risk of being banned.  If there is something you're interested in using, check it out thoroughly before you use it to ensure that it's not black listed.

Comment: You do not run the risk of being banned, as it has been publically stated that no one is infinity ward are no longer maintaining that game. I am not endorcing cheating but its just a fact

Comment: I've just noticed the original name of this post was "PS3 Modern Warfare 3" so the worry is irrelevant.  Thanks all the same, Flaunting, I didn't know that they'd pulled support for it.

Comment: they pulled support about 2 months after black ops 2 was released. although many believe they pulled support about 2 weeks after mw3 was released lol

Answer (score 0):

Exploding money is actually a "reward" effect for getting a payback kill, or being killed by someone you recently killed. There is no way to disable it.